# Navigating away from page should not pop up caution on certatin conditions javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to display a pop up stating that there are unsaved changes on page. Whenever, save button of my form is enabled and user tries to navigate away from page i need to show this pop up.

The problem is that on click of SAVE button i make an AJAX call to store data in backend. If AJAX call is success then i redirect the user to some other page.As we are navigating away from current page i get the unsaved data pop up.

So, basically i do not want to display the pop up when the redirect is done due to successful SAVE. 
Here is the code i have used

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
    var disabled = $("#save").is(":disabled");
    if(!disabled){
        var msg = "save data before navigating.";
        return evt = evt || window.event,
        evt.returnValue = msg, msg
        }
    }
  });
```

I also tried using `document.activeElement` to check if the focused button is the SAVE button . But `document.activeElement` does not work correctly in MAC browsers more specifically on  FireFox (47.0.1 on Mac) and also on Safari(Mac and windows).
Please suggest alternatives, to detect that navigation is due to click on SAVE button

Comment: The `return` statement is ending the function. The assignment after it will never be executed.

Comment: Why are you returning the event? You're supposed to return the message.

Comment: The simplest solution could be to use a flag, either global, or as part of some state-tracking object. Let's say the flag is `canShowPopup`, and is `true` by default. When the ajax call succeeds and before you transfer the user somewhere else, you set it to `false`. Then when that new page loads you set it back to `true` so everything resets.